# cpp: Object in a Inherited class -> getting zeros for everything in inherited class

Tags: c++, inheritance

i went into a trouble and i need your help
I have one main class and inhterited one from my main class

here is my main class

```
class NBAPlayer {
protected:
    char *ime;
    char tim[40];
    double prosekBrPoeni;
    double prosekBrAsistencii;
    double prosekBrSkokovi;
public:

    NBAPlayer(char *ime="",char *tim="",double prosekBrPoeni=0,double prosekBrAsistencii=0,double prosekBrSkokovi=0) {
        this->ime = new char [strlen(ime)+1];
        strcpy(this->ime,ime);
        strcpy(this->tim,tim);
        this->prosekBrPoeni=prosekBrPoeni;
        this->prosekBrAsistencii=prosekBrAsistencii;
        this->prosekBrSkokovi=prosekBrSkokovi;
    }

    NBAPlayer (const NBAPlayer &nbp) {
        this->ime = new char [strlen(ime)+1];
        strcpy(this->ime,nbp.ime);
        strcpy(this->tim,nbp.tim);
        this->prosekBrPoeni=nbp.prosekBrPoeni;
        this->prosekBrAsistencii=nbp.prosekBrAsistencii;
        this->prosekBrSkokovi=nbp.prosekBrSkokovi;
    }

    NBAPlayer &operator =(const NBAPlayer &nbp) {
        if (this!=&nbp) {
            delete [] ime;
            this->ime = new char [strlen(ime)+1];
            strcpy(this->ime,nbp.ime);
            strcpy(this->tim,nbp.tim);
            this->prosekBrPoeni=nbp.prosekBrPoeni;
            this->prosekBrAsistencii=nbp.prosekBrAsistencii;
            this->prosekBrSkokovi=nbp.prosekBrSkokovi;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~NBAPlayer() {
        delete [] ime;
    }

    double rating() {
        /*double poeni = prosekBrPoeni* (45/100);
        double asistencii = prosekBrAsistencii *(30/100);
        double skokovi = prosekBrSkokovi * (25/100);
        double vkupno = poeni+asistencii+skokovi;
        return vkupno; */

        return prosekBrPoeni* (45/100) + prosekBrSkokovi * (25/100) +prosekBrAsistencii *(30/100);
    }

    void print() {
        cout<<ime<<" - "<<tim<<endl;
        cout<<"Points: "<<prosekBrPoeni<<endl;
        cout<<"Assists: "<<prosekBrAsistencii<<endl;
        cout<<"Rebounds: "<<prosekBrSkokovi<<endl;
        cout<<"Rating: "<<rating()<<endl;
    }

};
```

This is my Inherited class

```
class AllStarPlayer: public NBAPlayer {
private:
    double allstarpoeni;
    double allstarasists;
    double allstarskok;
public:
    AllStarPlayer() {
        this->allstarpoeni=allstarpoeni=0;
        this->allstarasists=allstarasists=0;
        this->allstarskok=allstarskok=0;
    }
    AllStarPlayer(char *ime,char *tim,double prosekBrPoeni,double prosekBrAsistencii,double prosekBrSkokovi,double allstarpoeni,double allstarasists,double allstarskok)
        :NBAPlayer(ime,tim,prosekBrPoeni,prosekBrAsistencii,prosekBrSkokovi) {
        //this->n = n;
        this->allstarpoeni=allstarpoeni;
        this->allstarasists=allstarasists;
        this->allstarskok=allstarskok;
    }
    AllStarPlayer(NBAPlayer &n,double allstarpoeni,double allstarasists,double allstarskok)
        :NBAPlayer(ime,tim,prosekBrPoeni,prosekBrAsistencii,prosekBrSkokovi) {
        this->allstarpoeni=allstarpoeni;
        this->allstarasists=allstarasists;
        this->allstarskok=allstarskok;
    }

    AllStarPlayer (AllStarPlayer &a) {
        this->allstarpoeni=a.allstarpoeni;
        this->allstarasists=a.allstarasists;
        this->allstarskok=a.allstarskok;
    }

    AllStarPlayer &operator = (const AllStarPlayer &a) {
        if (this!=&a) {
            this->allstarpoeni=a.allstarpoeni;
            this->allstarasists=a.allstarasists;
            this->allstarskok=a.allstarskok;
        }
    }

    ~AllStarPlayer() {}

    double allStarRating() {
        double poeni = allstarpoeni* (30/100);
        double asistencii = allstarasists *(40/100);
        double skokovi = allstarskok * (30/100);
        double vkupno = poeni+asistencii+skokovi;
        return vkupno;
    }

    double rating() {
        return (NBAPlayer::rating()+allStarRating())/2;
    }

    void print() {
        NBAPlayer::print();
        cout<<"All Star Rating: "<<allStarRating()<<endl;
        cout<<"New Rating: "<<rating()<<endl;
    }


};
```

And the main function

```
int main() {

    char name[50];
    char team[40];
    double points;
    double assists;
    double rebounds;
    double allStarPoints;
    double allStarAssists;
    double allStarRebounds;

    NBAPlayer * players = new NBAPlayer[5];
    AllStarPlayer * asPlayers = new AllStarPlayer[5];
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    if (n == 1) {

        cout << "NBA PLAYERS:" << endl;
        cout << "=====================================" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            cin >> name >> team >> points >> assists >> rebounds;
            players[i] = NBAPlayer(name,team,points,assists,rebounds);
            players[i].print();
        }
    } else if (n == 2) {

        for (int i=0; i < 5; ++i) {
            cin >> name >> team >> points >> assists >> rebounds;
            cin >> allStarPoints >> allStarAssists >> allStarRebounds;
            players[i] = NBAPlayer(name,team,points,assists,rebounds);
            asPlayers[i] = AllStarPlayer(players[i],allStarPoints,allStarAssists,allStarRebounds);
        }

        cout << "NBA PLAYERS:" << endl;
        cout << "=====================================" << endl;
        for (int i=0; i < 5; ++i)
            players[i].print();

        cout << "ALL STAR PLAYERS:" << endl;
        cout << "=====================================" << endl;
        for (int i=0; i < 5; ++i)
            asPlayers[i].print();

    } else if (n == 3) {

        for (int i=0; i < 5; ++i) {
            cin >> name >> team >> points >> assists >> rebounds;
            cin >> allStarPoints >> allStarAssists >> allStarRebounds;
            asPlayers[i] = AllStarPlayer(name, team, points, assists, rebounds,
                                         allStarPoints,allStarAssists,allStarRebounds);
        }
        cout << "ALL STAR PLAYERS:" << endl;
        cout << "=====================================" << endl;
        for (int i=0; i < 5; ++i)
            asPlayers[i].print();

    }

    delete [] players;
    delete [] asPlayers;
}
```

Now when i use case 1 or this example

```
1
Nikola_Jokic Denver_Nuggets 18.3 6.1 10.6
Lonzo_Ball Los_Angeles_Lakers 10.2 7.2 6.9
Donovan_Mitchell Utah_Jazz 20.4 3.6 3.7
Ben_Simmons Philadelphia_76ers 16 8.2 8.2
Kristaps_Porzingis New_York_Knicks 22.7 1.2 6.6
```

Everything is okay but my rating is always 0, i don't know why, where is my mistake, also when i use different case such a case 2 or 3, when i came in front of my inherited class i get zeros for everything not only for my rating.

What i need to change in my first class to get the right result for rating? - first case

Is my inherited constructor wrong? - second case